# Regex in c# to replace \" with "

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string

```
string str = "\"PDORB9-AG, 16 1/2\"\" BIAS UNIT ASSY, ORBIT 900\"";
```

I need the output in this format

```
"PDORB9-AG, 16 1/2"" BIAS UNIT ASSY, ORBIT 900"
```

I tried this regex

```
Regex re = new Regex("[\"]");
str = str.Replace(re, " ").Trim();
```

But the str returns in output as `"PDORB9-AG, 16 1/2 BIAS UNIT ASSY, ORBIT 900"`
the quotes are missing next to 1/2. How to solve this??
Any leads appreciated

Comment: It's always the first and last characters of the string?

Comment: But `"PDORB9-AG, 16 1/2"" BIAS UNIT ASSY, ORBIT 900"` is an invalid string...?

Comment: @Liam although it is valid as the _contents_ of the string

Comment: @Liam wrong duplicate. There's nothing to replace in this string, the OP mistook the escaped debugger view for a non-existent `\ `

Comment: OP wants a string with quotation marks `2""` in it. So he needs the `\ ` or else it won't work. Either way...

Comment: @user2990856 there's nothing to replace. In most languages you have to *escape* double quotes. In most of them the escape character is `\ `

Comment: @Liam the OP is asking how to replace the non-existent `\ ` character. By doing so the regex *removed* the quotes. The OP should do *nothing* to the string

Comment: I mean I have to deserialize str by removing "\" and get the data in the required format

Answer (score 0):

Your string already has the format you want.

```
string str = "\"PDORB9-AG, 16 1/2\"\" BIAS UNIT ASSY, ORBIT 900\"";
```

Means that `str` holds the value `"PDORB9-AG, 16 1/2"" BIAS UNIT ASSY, ORBIT 900"`